# API Rate Limiting on Go

Tags: go

I have a routes.go file that looks like this:

```
func GetRouter(services Servicesr) *mux.Router {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/api/)

    return router
}
```

I want to rate limit my /api/services, and I am trying to do something like this:

in limiter.go I have this:

```
package limiter
import (
    "golang.org/x/time/rate"
    "net/http"
)

var limiter = rate.NewLimiter(1, 3)

func Limit(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if limiter.Allow() == false {
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(429), http.StatusTooManyRequests)
            return
        }

        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

but I can't seem to grasp my head around how I can rate limit the router.HandlerFunc for api/services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `router.HandleFunc` line for `api/services` to the following:

```
router.Handle("/api/services", Limit(http.HandlerFunc(services.GetServices))).Methods(http.MethodGet)
```

Comment: Tried wrapping it like that but getting this: "type does not implement 'http.Handler' as some methods are missing ServeHTTP(ResponseWriter, *Request)". I also had to use the import like this Limiter.Limit(services.GetServices)).Methods(http.MethodGet))